# Is there any project to calculate different hashes like md5, sha1 etc. in solidity?

Tags: hash-algorithm

I'm looking for solditiy-code to generate hashes of different hash-algorithms

- MD5
- SHA1
- SHA512

and more. Is there any project which implemented hash-algorithms in solidity?

Is there someone out there who also needs this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A pure Solidity version of SHA1 can be found in [this](https://github.com/Arachnid/solsha1) repository. (See [`sha1.sol`](https://github.com/Arachnid/solsha1/blob/master/contracts/sha1.sol) to jump to the code.)

From the README:

> Pure-solidity implementation of the SHA1 hash function, heavily
>   optimised using inline-assembly.
>
> Gas consumption is approximately 56k per 512 bit block.

Answer (score 0):

Solidity implements several hash function:

- RIPEMD-160
- SHA-256
- Ethereum-SHA-3 (Keccak-256)

You can find additional information on the [solidity website](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/miscellaneous.html#global-variables).